# Engine initialization returns an error while on IIS but perfect on localHost

Tags: c#, iis

I have been creating web-service for SecuSearch SDK pro, which were running absolutely fine,on local
but its engine fails to initialize on IIS. It is reading a licence file placed on C:\...  .
For check purpose I have read the .dat lisence file and its reading correct too.

> ```
>     [WebMethod]
>    public void init()
>    {
>        Int32 iError = 0;
>        SS_EngineParam pEngineParam;
>        pEngineParam = new SS_EngineParam();
>        pEngineParam.CandidateNumber = m_NumCandList;
>        pEngineParam.MemPoolSizeMB = SIZE_MEMORY_POOL;
>        //pEngineParam.szLicenseFile = SECUSEARCH_LICENSE_FILE;
> ```

```
       string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SecuGen\\SecuSearch SDK Pro\\License\\temp_license.dat");

       // Display the file contents to the console. Variable text is a string.
       System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteText.txt = {0}", text);
       if (IsWow64())
           pEngineParam.szLicenseFile = SECUSEARCH_LICENSE_FILE_x64;
       else
           pEngineParam.szLicenseFile = SECUSEARCH_LICENSE_FILE;

       // Initialize SecuSearch Engine.
       m_SecuSearch = new SecuSearch();
       iError = m_SecuSearch.InitializeEngine(pEngineParam);// here it returns an error 2006

       if (iError == (Int32)SS_Error.ERROR_NONE)
       {
           OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
           string oradb = "Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=.....;Password=.....";
           con.ConnectionString = oradb;
           con.Open();
           String strCommmand = "SELECT user_id, finger_no, sample_no, template_b64encoded FROM ForFDxSample";

           OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strCommmand, con);

           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

           string x;
           OracleDataReader objDataReader = null;
           try
           {
               objDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               if (objDataReader.HasRows)
               {
                   while (objDataReader.Read())
                   {
                       SS_IDInfo idInfo;
                       idInfo = new SS_IDInfo();
                       idInfo.ID = Convert.ToInt32(objDataReader[0]);
                       //       idInfo.FingerNumber = Convert.ToByte(objDataReader[1]);
                       idInfo.SampleNumber = Convert.ToByte(objDataReader[2]);
                       String template = objDataReader[3].ToString();

                       Byte[] minData;
                       minData = Convert.FromBase64String(template);
                        iError = m_SecuSearch.RegisterFP(minData, idInfo);



                   }

               }
           }
           catch (OracleException err)
           {
               String Text = err.ToString();
           }

           objDataReader.Close();
           cmd.Dispose();
           con.Close();

       }
   }
```

this is the init code.

> iError = m_SecuSearch.InitializeEngine(pEngineParam);// here it returns an error 2006

i am using MVC2

Comment: yes i have changed the default settings that's why i can read the license.dat file. just in case if this was the problem.

Comment: does the IIS user have correct access rights to the engine.

Comment: if it is how we assign rights by going to properties->security->edit-add->IIS_IUSRS 
and allowing full control.
then i have done it, to every possible folder.
or is there any other way,Please guide?

Comment: Security via the IIS Manager. By going to the site or virtual folder then going to Edit Permissions and then the security tab

Comment: its good here too, IIS_USRS with full control
i even have tried with full medium low trust levels.but nothing is happening

Comment: have you installed the secugen drivers on the server, and are you running on the correct operationg system [requirements for secusearch](http://www.secugen.com/products/sdk_pro.htm#secusearch)

Comment: i am using IIS server on the same PC, where i was using the local host. 
are you saying to  install drivers on IIS itself?

Comment: No, on the same machine. I thought you had deployed to a different server and now using IIS. If it's on the same machine then the drivers should be there otherwise you'd have had issues before.

Comment: Yeah and  drivers folder have access rights to IIS_IUSRS

Comment: Have you looked in the developer manual to see if it says what a 2006 error is since this is generated by the SDK.

Comment: Hey thanks for the hint, Let me find that and then update you.

Comment: Solved. I had to go to local security policy-> “User Rights Assignment” under Security Settings
Select “Lock pages in memory” and open its Properties.
add user IIS_IUSRS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

1. I had to go to local security policy-> “User Rights Assignment” under
   Security Settings
2. Select “Lock pages in memory” and open its
   Properties.
3. add user IIS_IUSRS